# Loop through JSON string and create dynamic JS output

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Basically, I'm grabbing information from and API and outputing it in JS. Currently, I have things working in PHP. Instead of outputing JS with PHP, I would like to make it cacheable in a JS file. Using WordPress, I've grabbed the API information, json encoded it, and localized it for use in JS.

Here is my new JS var with the JSON string information:

```
var discographyJson = php_params.discography_setup.replace( /&quot;/g, '"' );
```

This JSON output looks something like this:

```
{
    "discography": [
        {
            "album_id":1,
            "tracks":[
                {"title":"Track 1 of Album 1"},
                {"title":"Track 2 of Album 1"},
                {"title":"Track 3 of Album 1"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "album_id":2,
            "tracks":[
                {"title":"Track 1 of Album 2"},
                {"title":"Track 2 of Album 2"},
                {"title":"Track 3 of Album 2"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I would like to do, is loop through that content using JS/jQuery and create the following output, if possible.

```
$( '#album_1' ).click( function() {
    myPlaylist.setPlaylist([
        { title: "Track 1 of Album 1" },
        { title: "Track 2 of Album 1" },
        { title: "Track 3 of Album 1" }
    ]);
});

$( '#album_2' ).click( function() {
    myPlaylist.setPlaylist([
        { title: "Track 1 of Album 2" },
        { title: "Track 2 of Album 2" },
        { title: "Track 3 of Album 2" }
    ]);
});
```

Not being a JS/jQuery guru, I've racked my brain an spent many hours getting things this far. I cannot figure out how to loop through the JSON data to setup the jQuery functions. However, I've learned a bunch from the hours of trial and error debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, that you already have parsed the JSON String into a real JSON-Object, I think this should be the way to go:

```
$.each(discographyJson.discography, function(index, el) {
    $("#album_" + el.album_id).click(function() {
        var album = el;
        myPlaylist.setPlaylist(album.tracks);
    });
});
```

Note, that the album-variable is essential. If you don't assign `el` to `album` here, you would always use only the last element of the discography.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '#album_1' ).click( function() {
//i assume the json is parsed    
  myPlaylist.setPlaylist([
        { title: json.discography[0].tracks[0].title },
        { title: json.discography[0].tracks[1].title } ,
        { title: json.discography[0].tracks[2].title }                
    ]);

$( '#album_2' ).click( function() {
myPlaylist.setPlaylist([
    { title: json.discography[1].tracks[0].title },
    { title: json.discography[1].tracks[0].title },
    { title: json.discography[1].tracks[0].title }
]);


});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this will work. I am grabbing the info from an API, in which case I would't know the album ID, how many albums, or what the tracks are. It would need to be more dynamic. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for(var i = 0;i<json.discography.length;i++){
    (function(i){
        $('div').append(
            $('<a/>',{html:json.discography[i].album_id}).click(
                function(){
                    console.log(json.discography[i].tracks);
                }
            )
        )
     })(i);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dqafg/

Comment: Why do you wrap that stuff into an inner function?

Comment: i wrapped it in a closure so that `i` has the correct value on click

Comment: I see. But don't you think a variable would be more verbose? Anyways, no serious critic here.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this step?

```
var discographyJson = php_params.discography_setup.replace( /&quot;/g, '"' );
```

There is no reason to do this and it will require you to run JSON.parse which is just a waste of time.

Have the php write the JSON object correctly to the file making sure that the JSON file has the content type set

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
ADD CACHING HEADERS
WRITE OUT JSON HERE
```

Now use jQuery's get to fetch the JSON

```
$.get('yourBackend.php', processResults);
```

Now to loop through the JSON data

```
function setAlbumElem( id, tracks ){
    $("#album_" + id).click( 
        function(){
           myPlaylist.setPlaylist( tracks );
        }
    );

}

function processResults(data) {
    var discs = data.discography;  //could use jQuery each here
    for(var i=0;i<discs.length; i++){
         setAlbumElem(curDisc.album_id, curDisc.tracks);
    }
}
```

Comment: Intially, I was just trying to get the wp_localize_scrpt() to work as shown here: http://www.ronakg.com/2011/05/passing-php-array-to-javascript-using-wp_localize_script/#comments. I'll give your method a try. I appreciate your help!